# Web Services and IIS pass through/redirect

Tags: java, web-services, iis, redirect, proxy

We have a java application deployed in JBoss on one of our client's servers.  The application has to issue a web service call to a server completely outside of the network.
Unfortunately, our client's server is not exposed to the outside world and is not able to issue a web service request.  The client has IIS running on another server and we thought to route our web service calls through IIS.

We are not a Microsoft shop so know very little about how to do this.  We set up a Redirect but unfortunately, as soon as our web service hits IIS it automatically issues a 302 response. That is not what we want, we just want the web service call to pass through the IIS and be forwarded to the server hosting the web services.  We then want the response coming back from the server be forwarded through the IIS to the client's application server.  Essentially, we want IIS to serve as a pass through proxy.
Is there any way to set something like this up?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set up IIS as a reverse proxy for your internal server.  I had the same question and had better luck looking under reverse proxy information.

We are using IIS 8.5 and required IIS extensions for "Application Request Routing" and "URL Rewriting".  Not as scary as it sounds, these are not unusual IIS features to install.  The documentation rarely mentions web services specifically, but it seems to work for web services as it does for other web sites.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Application Request Routing would definitely be the way to go provided your running IIS 7 or later. We use it to implement proxies and reverse proxies extensively in our systems, handling both normal http and web service requests (caching of web services is a bit tricky).

A good starting point would be the following article by Ruslan Yakushev: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing